# NameError: name 'rclpy' is not defined

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i run `ros2 run python_parameters param_talker`,NameError: name 'rclpy' is not defined hapend.
And when i open`python_parameters_node.py`in pycharm, i found `No module named 'rclpy'`.
I dont konw why,and i dont konw how to solve it.
Does someone konw? I would really appreciate your help!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373946/nameerror:-name-%27rclpy%27-is-not-defined/) by [Ataraxy](https://answers.ros.org/users/65581/ataraxy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2021-03-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vonunwerth](https://answers.ros.org/users/34864/vonunwerth/) on 2021-03-15**:
Did you start your pycharm from a terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you didn't install python3 in fully.

Does your code has this line on the top? Like this line:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

You aren't using any conda or ancoda, right?

---

Originally posted by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) with karma: 113 on 2021-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ataraxy](https://answers.ros.org/users/65581/ataraxy/) on 2021-03-17**:
I think i install python3 in fully,but maybe not use conda.I set up a pythonpath and  i added the path of 'rclpy' file.it workd, but why?

**Comment by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) on 2021-03-18**:
So, that was the path issue then! I'm glad things fixed on your end! Could you mark your answer as "green check"? So others can get some idea to update their work.